# Why are two functions from class.h not recognized on class.cpp?

Tags: c++, class

I'm starting with C++ and maybe this isn't the best way to submit the question, just tell me if so.

I'm having a problem with two functions on GraphImp.h, I've implemented them on GraphImp.cpp and used the suggested firm from Visual Studio yet it won't recognize it, when I try to create a new graph it will tell me it's an abstract class.

GraphImp.h

```
#ifndef GRAPHIMP_H
#define GRAPHIMP_H

#include "Iterable.h"
#include "FuncionHash.h"
#include "FuncionCosto.h"
#include "Tupla.h"
#include "Array.h"
#include "Lista.h"
#include "ListaOrdEnc.h"
#include "Grafo.h"
#include "ColaPrioridad.h"
#include "FuncionCosto.h"
#include "Tabla.h"
#include "TablaAbierto.h"

typedef unsigned int nat;

template <class V, class A>
class GrafoImp : public Grafo<V, A>{
public:

    Matriz<bool> AdyacentMatrix() const;
        void LoadEdges(Puntero<ColaPrioridad <Tupla<V, V, A>, int>> cola, const FuncionCosto<V, A>& costo) const;

private:
    ...
};


#include "GraphImp.cpp"
#endif
```

GraphImp.cpp:

```
#ifndef GRAFOIMP_CPP
#define GRAFOIMP_CPP

#include "GrafoImp.h"

template<class V, class A>
Matriz<bool> GrafoImp<V, A>::AdyacentMatrix() const
{
    Matriz<bool> output = Matriz<bool>(vertices.ObtenerLargo());
foreach(Tupla<V, V, A> arista, aristas->ObtenerIterador()) {
    int i = this->ObtenerIndice(arista.ObtenerElemento1());     
    int j = this->ObtenerIndice(arista.ObtenerElemento2());
    output[i][j] = true;
}
return output;
}


template<class V, class A>
void GrafoImp<V, A>::LoadEdges(Puntero<ColaPrioridad<Tupla<V, V, A>, int>> cola, const FuncionCosto<V, A>& costo) const{
    ...
}
```

Graph.h

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

#include "Iterable.h"
#include "FuncionHash.h"
#include "FuncionCosto.h"
#include "Tupla.h"
#include "Array.h"
#include "Lista.h"
#include "ListaOrdEnc.h"
#include "Matriz.h"
#include "ColaPrioridad.h"

enum TipoConexo 
{
    NO_CONEXO, DEBILMENTE_CONEXO, FUERTEMENTE_CONEXO
};

typedef unsigned int nat;

template <class V, class A>
class Graph abstract 
{
public:
    ...
    virtual Matriz<bool> AdyacentMatrix() const abstract;
    virtual void LoadEdges(Puntero<ColaPrioridad <Tupla<V, V, A>, int>> cola, const FuncionCosto<V, A>& costo) const abstract;
};

#endif
```

Sorry about the spanish, I've translated the essentials so I think it will be legible ;)

Comment: Your example code is incomplete. Post a [MCVE] next time please.

Comment: How so? I've added the private, and the bottom #include "GraphImp.cpp" in GraphImp.h. Is there anything else?

Comment: You added the missing stuff now, yes. However read the duplicate question's answers to solve your problem.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!